# Why is Instruments reporting memory leaks in this code?

Tags: iphone, ipad, memory-management, ios, instruments

Quick question, Instruments is reporting a leak here...

```
MyViewController *myVC = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"myView" bundle:nil];     
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myVC animated:YES];  //<<<<---- !00% leak according to Instruments
[myVC release];
```

I understand the myVC is retained by the nav controller, so I assume the nav controller releases them when the view is popped off the nav stack?

Also, there's another tricky one in one of my loops, the static analyzer is reporting a potential leak here...

```
//Walk through the scheduled alarms and create notifications
NSMutableArray *fireDates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(NSDate *fireDate in fireDates)          //<<<<---- Static analyzer is reporting potential leak here
{
     UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (localNotif == nil)
    {
        [fireDates release];
        return;
    }

    localNotif.fireDate = fireDate;  
    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    localNotif.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", alarm.Label];
    localNotif.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(@"Launch", nil);

    localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

    localNotif.userInfo = infoDict;
    localNotif.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
    [localNotif release];

}
[fireDates release];
```

Do I need to somehow release fireDate?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: static analyzer is generally very good... maybe don't ommit the missing code...

Comment: thanks, Eiko, i just updated my question to include the missing code.  your thoughts?

Comment: are you running the test against simulator or device?  I noticed that against simulator, leaks program shows faulty leaks.

Comment: @joo - i'm running the test against the simulator.  i'll try it on my device, thanks.

Comment: @joo - i tried it on the device and the same nav controller leak is still being caught.  your thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These snippets are both fine, as snippets go.  Without seeing your full code it's impossible to say if you don't do something silly elsewhere. Do you ever release your navigationController (in your app delegate `-dealloc`, likely)?  That's a leak that doesn't mean much, but it could be what is triggering the first warning.

---

**Edit**: with regards to the second snippet, the code looks fine (though the shortcut return case will bother some coders, who would rather see a `break` statement).  The static analyzer may be bothered by the lack of a `[localNotif release]` (even though it's obviously unnecessary) in the conditional return.

Comment: thanks, seamus!  no, i don't release my nav controller in my app delegate's -dealloc because the nav controller is created in my nib mainwindow.xib nib file.  therefor, i shouldn't have to release it in my -dealloc, right?

Comment: Do you have an outlet set to the navigation controller?

Comment: @christo16 - no, i don't because I don't have an instance var for my nav controller.  i just use [self navigationController] for everything.  your thoughts?

Comment: If you have a root view in a nib that isn't held in an IBOutlet, I don't know what code releases it.  I suspect that this is, in fact, your leak.  Try adding an IBOutlet ivar or property to your app delegate class and releasing it in `-dealloc`.  It's a useful data point even if it's not the case, and it's a minor change to your code.

Comment: The `return` statement is definitely triggering the static analyzer -- a simple memory leak of `fireDates` will occur if the allocation of `localNotif` fails.

Comment: @seamus - well i added the outlets and i'm still getting the leaks, so i'll keep looking.  you're right, tho, it's a good data point.  if you can think of anything else, let me know.  thanks again!

Comment: @Shaggy Frog - I'm staring at the code and failing to see the leak of `fireDates` you mention.  It's released immediately before the return statement.  Am I missing something blindingly obvious?

Comment: IBOutlets are your responsibility. If there's a property, it sets the property (you have to set it to nil in dealloc). If there's no property but there's an ivar, it autoreleases the old value, retains the new value, and performs the assignment. see key-value coding Accessor Search Patterns: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Concepts/SearchImplementation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000955

Comment: Oops -- you're right. The static analyzer is complaining about localNotif, then, just as you say, since there's no explicit release (that isn't required, implicitly). So +1 for better eyes than me.

Answer (score 0):

In the first snippet, what is being leaked? Instruments will tell you the line where it was allocated, which is often not the line "responsible" for the leak (of course, line numbers tend to be off because it gives you the return address, not the calling address). I'm assuming it's MyViewController being leaked, and that instruments is actually complaining about alloc (look in the backtrace, cmd-E I think).

If you click on the arrow next to the memory address (you might have to click around a bit and hover over the leak address; I don't remember) you'll see all the alloc/retain/release/autorelease/malloc/free/CFRetain/CFRelease calls on that address. Ignore the ones before alloc (those are for a previous object which happened to live at the same address). Match retains and (auto)releases. You can match an autorelease with the corresponding (delayed) release, because the delayed release will happen when NSAutoreleasePool is release (which is evident in the stack trace). Look for a retain without a matching (auto)release. That's the leak.

In the second case, it helps if you tell us what Clang SA is telling you (click the little triangle on the left and it expands to show you the control-flow where the leak occurs).

But I don't think the loop runs at all, because `fireDates` is empty.